# AngularJS modules Dependency in JasmineJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm with a problem when I use Jasmine and AngularJS.

My app.js in AngularJS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps']);
```

In Jasmine I'm make this example below:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    beforeEach(
        function () {
            module('myApp');
        }
    );

    describe('GeoLocationController', 
        function () {

            var _controller,
                _scope,
                _service;

            beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
                _scope = $rootScope.$new();

                _controller = $controller('GeoLocationController', { 
                    '$scope': _scope,
                    'GeoLocationService': _service
                });
            }));

            it('exists', inject(
                function ($controller) {
                    expect(_controller).toBeDefined();
                    expect(_controller).not.toBeNull();
                    expect(typeof _controller).toBe('object');
                }
            ));
        }
    );
}());
```

When I removed ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'] in my app Angular, Jasmine worked.

I try:

```
beforeEach(
    function () {
        module('uiGmapgoogle-maps');
        module('myApp');
    }
);

beforeEach(
    function () {
        module('uiGmapgoogle-maps', []);
        module('myApp', []);
    }
);

beforeEach(
    function () {
        module('myApp', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps']);
    }
);
```

Thanks for all!

Comment: Which part does not work? It sounds like you are saying that you fixed this.

Comment: can you please add the jasmine error?